# Hibernate Criteria - get count of subselect

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, count, criteria

I would like to count the number of events that fulfill a certain condition.  If the row count is less than a million I would like to get the actual number.  If it is more than a million I do not need to know the exact number and it is ok to return the count as 1 million.

I thought about this query

```
select count(*) from (select id from events where x=10  limit 1000000) a
```

How can it be done Detached Criteria / sub criteria?

Is there a better way of doing it other than the above sql? I'm using postgresql 9.3

Answer (score 1):

That query won't perform better than a regular count, so try this instead:

```
long count = ((Number) 
    session.createCriteria(Event.class)
           .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
           .add(Restrictions.eq("x", 10))
           .uniqueResult()).longValue();
long countLimit = Math.min(count, 1000000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The code "select count(*) from (select id from events where x=10  limit 1000000) a" run faster since it count at most 1M and not the entire table.  Doing the min after counting the entire table takes longer.

Comment: Unfortunately, Hibernate can only use sub-queries inside the WHERE clause. You cannot use table expressions. For that you need to use a native query.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood
You have to count some recode if it is >1000000 it should show 1 Million +
else exact count.
For  this you cat try this query

```
String t;
            t = (String) session.createQuery(
                    "select case when count(*)>1000000   "
                    + "then '1Million +' "
                    + "else count(*) "
                    + "end "
                    + "from events").uniqueResult();
               session.getTransaction().commit();

               System.out.println("size is " + t);
```

Use `CASE [ WHEN {test_conditional} THEN {match_result} ]* ELSE {miss_result} END`
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3280

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The performance with your query is the same as counting the entire table.  My aim is to stop counting when I reach 1M